# Merge rows in one dataframe which share the same index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filter

I would like to have a unique `DateTimeIndex` in a dataframe. Therefore, I would like to *merge two rows with the same index* into one row. During this merge, I would like to apply a custom formular (such as `avg/mean`, `max`, `min`) to each column.

Idea formulated in data:

A Dataframe with times series data

```
df_orig
+----------------------------+-------+--------+
|                            | value | value2 |
| ts                         |       |        |
+----------------------------+-------+--------+
| 2019-09-17T09:39:38.711111 | 10    | 10     |
+----------------------------+-------+--------+
| 2019-09-17T09:39:38.766666 | 1     | 3      |
+----------------------------+-------+--------+
| 2019-09-17T09:39:38.766666 | 2     | 6      |
+----------------------------+-------+--------+
| 2019-09-17T09:39:39.010101 | 2     | 4      |
+----------------------------+-------+--------+
```

i would try to mark those rows, which index is *not unique*. Like this:

```
df_marked_duplicated
+----------------------------+-------+--------+-----------+
|                            | value | value2 | is_unique |
| ts                         |       |        |           |
+----------------------------+-------+--------+-----------+
| 2019-09-17T09:39:38.711111 | 10    | 10     | 1         |
+----------------------------+-------+--------+-----------+
| 2019-09-17T09:39:38.766666 | 1     | 3      | 0         |
+----------------------------+-------+--------+-----------+
| 2019-09-17T09:39:38.766666 | 2     | 6      | 0         |
+----------------------------+-------+--------+-----------+
| 2019-09-17T09:39:39.010101 | 2     | 4      | 1         |
+----------------------------+-------+--------+-----------+
```

so that I can later calculate the `avg` on `value`and the `max` on `value2`. So the target df looks like:

```
 df_target
+----------------------------+-------+--------+-----------+
|                            | value | value2 | is_unique |
| ts                         |       |        |           |
+----------------------------+-------+--------+-----------+
| 2019-09-17T09:39:38.711111 | 10    | 10     | 1         |
+----------------------------+-------+--------+-----------+
| 2019-09-17T09:39:38.766666 | 1.5   | 6      | 0         |
+----------------------------+-------+--------+-----------+
| 2019-09-17T09:39:39.010101 | 2     | 4      | 1         |
+----------------------------+-------+--------+-----------+
```

I am not sure if `pd.groupby` isnt a bit overkill, because - from what I see - it forces me into iterating over it later. I am also interested into seeing how deduplication works in pandas more closely.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it just `groupby`:

```
df.groupby('ts').agg({'value':'mean', 'value2':'max'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas implementation of `aggregate` functions on `groupby` objects is performance efficient than any custom implementation. You can also apply different aggregate methods for different columns with `dict` of functions.

so in your case

```py
df.groupby(['ts'].agg({'value': 'mean', 'value2': 'max'})
```